# How was Daniel Lugo able to withdraw Victor Kershaw money from the bank?

Tags: plot-explanation, pain-and-gain

In the movie [Pain & Gain](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1980209/), How was Daniel Lugo (Mark Wahlberg) able to impersonate Victor Kershaw personality when he went into the bank in the Bahamas?

I find it hard to believe that any bank would let someone claim that he is the owner of the account without any identification.

Comment: You might want to read the real story of what happened here:
http://www.miaminewtimes.com/1999-12-23/news/pain-gain/

Answer (score 1):

He had Victor sign a power of attorney to Danny Lugo. If you have a notarized power of attorney signed by the bank account owner, that gives you full access to his account.